# Rails - Group a list of records by created_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating a job board, and to make it easy to navigate postings I'm hoping to group Jobs by on the day they were created. My current implementation works OK, but I'm wondering if there is a more performant way to approach this; something about adding two instance variables in the *new* method of the JobsController.

Below would be a great outcome for the list, ordered in descending order:

#### March 11

- Job F [id:6]
- Job E [id:5]
- Job D [id:4]

#### March 10

- Job C [id:3]
- Job B [id:2]
- Job A [id:1]

**JobsController < ApplicationController**

```
def index
  @jobs = Job.where(Job.arel_table[:created_at].gteq("%D")).order("created_at DESC")
  @job_days = @jobs.group_by { |job| job.created_at.to_date }
end
```

**index.html.haml**

```
- @job_days.each do |day, jobs|
  = day.strftime("%B %d")
  - jobs.each do |job|
    = link_to(job.url) do
      %h2= job.title
      %p= job.company
```

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Job.where('your conditions').group_by(&:created_at)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer @MikeA

Answer (score 1):

Try below query:

```
@results = Job.(Job.arel_table[:created_at].gteq("%D")).
  order("created_at DESC").
  group_by {
    |job| job.created_at.strftime("%B %d")
  }
```

View would become:

**index.html.haml**

```
- @results.each do |date, items|
  = date
  - items.each do |job|
    = link_to(job.url) do
      %h2= job.title
      %p= job.company
```

Comment: I'll try this and report back to you the results.

Comment: Refactoring the method requires modifying the view. It's unclear how how to display the date in view @vishal

Comment: @VegaStudios Updated answer please check it. :)

Comment: How is this query more performant than what I've already got? @vishal

Comment: @VegaStudios may be you got what you want.  right ?

Comment: Doesn't really answer my question; I'm wondering if there is a more performant way than my current approach

Comment: @VegaStudios this is the best way to group by particular field.

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn’t just,

```
Job.where(‘your conditions’).group(“DATE(created_at)”)
```

Work?

PS: This isn’t tested since I’m adding this from my phone.

Comment: Refactoring the instance method would require modifying the view. How do you reckon I display the date format without `@job_days`?

Comment: You can use `DATE` with any of aggregate function like count. Fetching records will raise `PG::GroupingError` error

Comment: Yeah,  we can not just fetch records, instead can be used with any other aggregate function like `count`